# Storing and Getting Dynamically Created List Elements with Buttons in Javascript - using LocalStorage

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, local-storage, buttonclick

I am making a todo list application where I am creating new list item when a user is adding a new task - and each list item comes with a dynamically generated button where we can marked the todo item done or pending - my requirement is that the todo list should be preserved even when the webpage is refreshed. I am using localstorage to store the innerHTML of the unordered list - and I am succesfully able to retrieve the list items with the buttons - but their onclick functionality is gone - as well as the glyphicon state of the buttons and the text decoration of the text is gone too.

```
var ul = document.getElementsByClassName("taskList");
var li = document.createElement("li");
li.setAttribute('class','taskListItem');
li.style.textDecoration = 'none';
li.innerHTML = inputValue;
var clearButton = document.createElement("button");
clearButton.setAttribute('class','btn btn-default');
clearButton.style.paddingTop = "5px";
clearButton.style.paddingBottom = "5px";
clearButton.style.cssFloat = "right";
clearButton.onclick = function(){
li.parentNode.removeChild(li); // This functionality is not available when the page is refreshed
}
```

Also how do I save the state of the button using LocalStorage - that is if the task is done - I am changing the glyphicon of the button

```
checkButton.onclick = function(){
console.log("li style decoration = "+li.style.textDecoration);
if(li.style.textDecoration == "none"){
    li.style.textDecoration = "line-through";
    var checkSpanLocal = checkButton.childNodes[0];
    checkSpanLocal.className = "glyphicon glyphicon-minus";
    }
}
```

Any type of help is appreciated.

Comment: You can use the $(document).on('click',.....) for dynamically added elements. http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: I know I can use jquery....but how to save and retrieve the onclick behaviour of the dynamic button I am generating...preferring Vanilla JS for simplicity.

Comment: Fair point - you can achieve the same thing by document.addEventListener. Eg: document.addEventListener('click',function(e){
    console.log("Hello world");
 })

Answer (score 0):

If i had understood correctly,

You want to preserve the values even after refreshed, hence you can preferably try using session storage instead of local storage. Local Storage meant to store values only for the session  and once you refresh it will be lost.

in es6, sessionStorage

Comment: Both do the same thing...but LocalSession data is there until explicitly deleted...I am looking for code snippet to do the same